# Convert normal, infix expression to arraylist of tokens

Tags: java, tokenize

I want to convert something like

233 + 4 *(4-8) +5

to [233,+,4,*,(,4,-,8,),+,5]

Where the latter is an array of Strings.

So far I have:

```
 String s = "233 + 4 *(4-8) +5";
 for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        String sub = s.substring(i,j);
        String checkdigit = s.substring(i,j);
        while(checkdigit.matches("\\d|\\.") && j<s.length())
        {
            checkdigit = s.substring(j,j+1);
            j++;
        }
        System.out.print(sub);
        if(!sub.equals(" ")) expression.add(sub);
    }
```

But I'm getting null pointer exceptions. Can someone help me correct this?

Also if anyone could help me parse this so that it accepted negative values (like -5) as well that would be helpful.

Edit:
By the way the . is for doubles (like 5.0)

Edit 2:

If anyone knows any Java API classes that can replace my code, please show how I could replace my code with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing an arithmetic expression is a bit more complicated than it seems first (for example it is difficult to distinguish between a minus mark and a negative number).

While you can write your own parser, I recommend you to use a general parser (e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/)) by providing your desired grammar to it or to look for a simpler arithmetic-specific library (e.g. [JEP](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) or some open-source equivalent).

Here is a link which help you to use ANTLR to parse a arithmetic expression:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3

Answer (score 0):

org.nfunk.jep.JEP works for most of the complex arithmetic parsing and is perfect for your requirement. Make sure you are downloading the latest jar (3.x.x i believe) for its usage. 2.x does not support some of the obvious functionality!